# Flutter: I have problem with Google Maps, when changing the page

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem with Google Maps in my Flutter app, when a page with a map inside is closing there is a delay with the map itself compared to the page(the map stays in the screen a little bit longer compare to the page). Do you have any ideas?

I tried changing the code structure, but no results

Comment: try adding some code examples and visual way to see the bug.